# Delphi & CSS - box model question

Tags: html, css, delphi, wysiwyg, css-position

I am using a windows based program, coded in Delphi, to generated HTML (and can restrict the browser to MSIE 7 +).

I need absolute, pixel perfect WYSIWYG. However, I am having text-wrap problems.

What looks like this in Delphi

```
-- -----------------
| aaaa bbb ccc ddd |
--------------------
```

looks like this in the browser (both MS IE and FF. Although I am targeting MSIE only, I am using FF to have access to FireDebug)

```
--------------------
|   aaaa bbb ccc   |
--------------------
ddd
```

Now, Delphi has an Object Inspector

[image]

which allows me to precisely set a control's top/left/width/height and when generating the HTML, I use those for CSS positioning of each control on the form. e.g.

```
<fieldset style="position: absolute; top: 56px; left: 32px; width: 185px; height: 13px; ">
  <legend> </legend>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 179px; height: 13px;">
     Label1 000 111 222 aaa bbb cccc dd
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

But since I am getting text wrap I guess that I am overlooking something, like setting of margin/border/padding. Any ideas what?

Btw, I use Arial 10 as my font for windows/browser comparability, so it shouldn't be a font size problem.

I think that Delphi must have something akin to the box model, insomuchas it draws the control with a margin (a control starting at 0 left has a visible gap from the left of the form; if I give it width 100 and position another with left =100 there is a visible gap between them).

Any idea how I am going to achieve WYSIWYG? The HTMl must reflect the control layout in the Delphi form.

Comment: What about removing `position: absolute;` and `width: 179px; height: 13px;` in the `<div style="` tag?

Comment: Sorry, I need that. What I have is a panel (represented as a FieldSet) which can contain multiple controls - in this case a single line of text (the TLabel), so the panel needs positioning and so do its contents.

Comment: Added the HTML tag to attract more knowledgeable crowds; Delphi is mostly irrelevant, once you know the correct markup for what you need, you'll be able to use whatever tool to make it happen.

Comment: I did actually try removing the styling on the text, though, but it didn't change anything; the text still wrapped and the end fell out of the fieldset. I am sure I need to consider margin, padding and border ...

Comment: is the fieldset in a form.. a form has default padding and/or margin if you have a form are they zero'd, and the font is it explicitly 10**px** maybe if no units there's a conflict?

Comment: the legend itself will be causing the fieldset to be differing heights even between IE7 & 8  - and a fieldset has differing default padding across browser so try zeroing the padding on it too

Comment: + 1 all round (and feel free to post answers, as well as comments. If someone gets it right, I will request that they post an answer and award the question to them.

Comment: @clairesuzy - yes, it is in a form, so I had best zero the margin and padding. Thanks

Comment: I also made sure that my text was  {
  font: 12px Arial;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

Comment: You have a good point about the fieldset legend (I don't want one, but I put a space because the HTML won't validate at W3C if I don't). I guess that that space has a font; may I should drop it?  (btw, the legend has the same font & padding as the fieldset & TLabel (text) - same CSS rule & the CSS validates at W3C)

Comment: @Cosmin Prund, I'm not so sure that we want to ignore Delphi for two reasons: 1) it has it's own form of "box model", which I don't yet understand, which is probably what is causing the problems, and, 2) since I am using Delphi to generate the HTML/CSS style, then maybe I need to apply a fudge factor to Delphi top/left/width/height?

Comment: Note that it still doesn't work, even if I remove the legend from the fieldset (thus invalidating the HTML)

Comment: Absolute Pixel Perfect WYSIWYG?  HA HA HA HA HA HA!  I'll +1 if you could find me any instance of that on the web.  Especially on any Microsoft-based browser....

Comment: @Mawg: Delphi doesn't have a "box model". It uses absolute pixel positioning, and standard Windows parenting for embedded controls; the "visible gap" you see with a control with left=0 is a beveled edge, which is just a drawing technique to add depth. Your question is "how do I create the absolute equivalent of this form in HTML using CSS?"; the fact that the form is designed in Delphi's IDE is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
  <form style="margin:0 0 0 0; padding:0 0 0 0;">
   <fieldset style="position: absolute; top: 56px; left: 32px; width: 185px; height: 18px; ">
     <legend></legend>
     <div style="text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 179px; height: 18px;">aaa bbb cccc dd</div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
</html>
```